# Create/merge an object hashmap from two arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that requires me to create a hashmap, it's my first one and after researching I am stuck. I need to create the map from two arrays.

*Array 1:*

```
var arrayOne = [ "board", "admin" ]
```

These would be added to a map Object with a default value of false, I can get to this part:

```
var myMap = {
    board: false,
    admin: false
}
```

*Array 2:*

```
var arrayTwo = [ "board" ]
```

Only 'board' exists here, so I want to turn the value to 'true'. I'm stuck on where to go next so I end up with:

```
var myMap = {
    board: true,
    admin: false
}
```

Here's my script so far:

```
var myMap = {};
var arrayOne = [ "board", "admin" ];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
    var a = arrayOne[i];
    myMap[a] = false; // sets default value
}
```

Any help to do the 'next bit' to merge the two is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Like this: http://ideone.com/tspfzc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should continue with the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length; i++) {
    if (arrayTwo[i] in myMap)
        myMap[arrayTwo[i]] = true;
}
```

... setting properties to `true` only if they exist in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf() method to check if the item is in second array or not

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

```
var myMap = {};
var arrayOne = [ "board", "admin" ];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
    var a = arrayOne[i];
    myMap[a] = false; // sets default value
    if ( arrayTwo.indexOf( a ) != -1 )
    {
        myMap[a] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, `indexOf` still has limited support.

Comment: @VisioN actually most browsers are supporting this http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 0):

Just do one then the other...

```
var i;
var myMap = {};
var arrayOne = [ "board", "admin" ];

for (i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
     myMap[arrayOne[i]] = false;
}

var arrayTwo = [ "board" ];

for (i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length; i++) {
     myMap[arrayTwo[i]] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ES5 version

```
arrayOne.forEach(function(item){
    myMap[item] = false;
});
arrayTwo.forEach(function(item){
    (item in myMap) && (myMap[item] = true);
});
```